# How to get data from promise to main function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have function:

```
function find(id){

    var res = this.db.query(this.knex(this.table).where({id:id}).select().toString());

    var props = {};

    for(var c in res.rows[0]){
        if(res.rows[0].hasOwnProperty(c))
            props[c] = res.rows[0][c];
    }

    return this.newRecord(props);

}
```

`this.db` here is `pg.Client` object from `pg` npm module. `knex` is an npm module too, it builds query to postgresql databse.
It returns promise, and I need to get data from this promise to main function, create object from this data and return it (`newRecord` function does it).

I have alredy tried installing node version 7 and using await, but that doesn't help because if function has `async` modifier, then it will return promise with object that comes after `return`, and I don't need this behaviour at all.

So, the question is how can I await for that promise to finish and get data from it, with or without `async/await` or any other es6 or es7 functionality?

Comment: by using a promise's `.then` method - `somepromise.then(function(result) { console.log(result); });`

Comment: @JaromandaX did you read my question? I need that data in main function, create object from it and return it **from main function**

Comment: yes, I did read the question, I'm telling you how promises work ... they **do not make asynchronous code synchronous** - which is what I suspect you want - and there is absolutely no power in the universe that will do that for you - once you use asynchronous code, the only way to access any results etc, is using the various asynchronous code methodologies (callbacks, promises, async/await) ... no other way ... embrace asynchronous code, rather than trying to beat it ... it will always win

Answer (score 0):

Pg Client Query method seems to be asynchronous function (since main function is not waiting for the query to return value to res and then proceed further). So, what you should do is pass a callback function to your query method as follow -

```js
function find(id){
    var res;
   this.db.query(this.knex(this.table).where({id:id}).select().toString(), function(err, result) {
      if(!err){
        console.log("Result is - " + result);
        res = result //if its an array, use res = result.splice();
        
         var props = {};

      for(var c in res.rows[0]){
        if(res.rows[0].hasOwnProperty(c))
            props[c] = res.rows[0][c];
     }

     return this.newRecord(props);

      }
      else {
        console.error("Error occured -" + err);
      }
    }
    );

   
});
```

Comment: I will check that later, thank you anyway. And also I have found deasync npm module that can do what I want. I will comment when I check.

Comment: My advice: learn how promises work instead of bypassing them.

Comment: This doesn't work, giving error "this.newRecord is not a function"